# JS CountUp With Decimal Places

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a "count up" JavaScript animation that can use both integers and decimal point values as inputs.

Currently, I have something in the works that is heavily based on this example: https://codepen.io/jshakes/pen/KKpjdYv

My variation allows for floating point (decimal point) numbers to be used as inputs (i.e 45.34).

I'm having some trouble allowing for both floating point AND whole numbers. Right now, the animation runs and results in floating point numbers for each value, so even if 110 is given as an input, the result in the DOM will be 110.00.

I've commented out a section in my code where I was trying to conditionally define `countTo` to allow for inputs that are whole numbers and decimal numbers, but I was running into some errors where `countTo` was undefined.

Does anyone have any clues as to how I could use this animation behavior with both floating points AND whole number values?

Instead of resulting in what I have currently in the DOM:

45.34

110.00

53210.00

I would like to have:

45.34

110

53210

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Link to codepen: https://codepen.io/jon424/pen/oNdJzKg

HTML

```
<button onclick="runAnimations()">Animate</button>
<ul>
  <li><span class="countup">45.34</span></li>
  <li><span class="countup">110</span></li>
  <li><span class="countup">53210</span></li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
const animationDuration = 2000;
const frameDuration = 1000 / 60;
const totalFrames = Math.round( animationDuration / frameDuration );
const easeOutQuad = t => t * ( 2 - t );

const animateCountUp = el => {
    let frame = 0;
    const countTo = parseFloat( el.innerHTML, 10 );
    const counter = setInterval( () => {
        frame++;
        const progress = easeOutQuad( frame / totalFrames );

 
  //if countTo is decimal number:
    const currentCount = ( countTo * progress ).toFixed(2); // :-)
//... else if countTo is a Whole Number ... currentCount = Math.round( countTo * progress );
    
        if ( parseInt( el.innerHTML, 10 ) !== this.currentCount ) {
            el.innerHTML = currentCount;
        }

        if ( frame === totalFrames ) {
            clearInterval( counter );
        }
    }, frameDuration );
};

const runAnimations = () => {
    const countupEls = document.querySelectorAll( '.countup' );
    countupEls.forEach( animateCountUp );
};
```

and, no, I cannot use the countUp class from GitHub :-) (https://inorganik.github.io/countUp.js/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe it works.

```
const countTo = Number(el.textContent);
```

`Number();` converts the number automatically.

it is not good practice to use `.innerHTML` to get this type of value use `.innerText` or `.textContent`.

Answer (score 0):

can check if it is integer and then check if it ends with ".00"

```
const animationDuration = 2000;
const frameDuration = 1000 / 60;
const totalFrames = Math.round( animationDuration / frameDuration );
const easeOutQuad = t => t * ( 2 - t );

const animateCountUp = el => {
    let frame = 0;
    const countTo = parseFloat( el.innerText, 10 );
    const counter = setInterval( () => {
        frame++;
        const progress = easeOutQuad( frame / totalFrames );

 
    const currentCount = ( countTo * progress ).toFixed(2);

    if(countTo.toString.slice(-3) !== ".00" && Number.isInteger(countTo) ) {
        currentCount = ( countTo * progress ).toFixed(2);
    }else if (Number.isInteger(countTo))else{
        currentCount = Math.round( countTo * progress );
    }else{
        currentCount = Math.round( countTo * progress );
    }

    
        if ( parseInt( el.innerText, 10 ) !== this.currentCount ) {
            el.innerHTML = currentCount;
        }

        if ( frame === totalFrames ) {
            clearInterval( counter );
        }
    }, frameDuration );
};

const runAnimations = () => {
    const countupEls = document.querySelectorAll( '.countup' );
    countupEls.forEach( animateCountUp );
};
```

Comment: hmm - I see what you are saying, but this is still not what I'm going for. I think the issue might(?) be with the `countTo` value? If the input (`el`) is a floating point number or an integer, the animation still animates with floating points.